# Несколько EditText в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-edittext

Вообщем вопрос такой. У меня layout, в котором один EditText. Я вывожу через recyclerView  на экран список из 4 позиций с одним и тем же EditText. Как можно добиться редактирования EditText одновременно для всех остальных EditText? То есть чтобы при вводе текста в одном поле ввода появлялся и в других полях тот же текст. Но не понимаю как сделать это в адаптере.
Направьте пожалуйста на правильный путь.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.AdapterViewHolder>  {
private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
public Context mContext;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<CurrencyItems>mListCur;
private ArrayList<CurrencyItems> cmList;


public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<CurrencyItems> cmList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.cmList = cmList;

}

interface ItemViewOrder {
    int TYPE_1 = 0;
    int TYPE_2 = 1;
    int TYPE_3 = 2;
    int TYPE_4 = 3;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new AdapterViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final CurrencyItems currencyItem = cmList.get(position);


    String ammount = currencyItem.getMountNumber();

 String currencyEqually = currencyItem.getRates();
    String result =          currencyItem.getResult();

    holder.ammount.setText(ammount);
    holder.currencyEqually.setText(currencyEqually);
    holder.result.setText(result);

    holder.ammount.setText("1");




        holder.ammount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {   //Convert the Text to String
                int a = Integer.parseInt(holder.ammount.getText().toString());

                String inputText = holder.ammount.getText().toString();
                holder.result.setText( String.valueOf(a*3));


            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
        });


     }


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cmList.size();
}




public class AdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public ImageView currencyIcon;
    public TextView abbCurrency;
    public TextView currencyName;
    public EditText ammount;

    public TextView currencyEqually;
    public TextView result;
    ////////////
    public LinearLayout container;

private void updateMultiply (){
int weight = Integer.valueOf(ammount.getText().toString());
int rate = 3;
result.setText(String.valueOf(weight * rate));}

    public AdapterViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        currencyIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.currency_icon);
        abbCurrency = itemView.findViewById(R.id.abb_currency);
        currencyName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.currency_name);
        ammount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mount_number);
        currencyEqually = itemView.findViewById(R.id.currency_equally);
        result = itemView.findViewById(R.id.result);
        container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);


   recyclerView  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
   mListCur = new ArrayList<>();
   Log.d(TAG, "cur" + currencyEqually.toString());


   itemView.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }
   @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "touch event" );
        if(getAdapterPosition()==0 && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Zero Touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), MainUsd.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
   }

        if(getAdapterPosition()==1 && event.getAction() == 
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Zero Touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), MainEuro.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
        }

        if(getAdapterPosition()==2 && event.getAction() == 
       MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Zero Touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), MainEuro.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
        }

        return true;


    }



  }


  }
```

Comment: Что именно вы имеете в виду? Вы хотите вводить текст в одном поле ввода и чтобы при этом в других появлялся тот же текст?

Comment: Да.именно так хочу сделать.Прошу прощения за формулировку

Comment: Попробуйте как-то так: 1. При вводе текста сохраняйте текст в переменную в адаптере. 2. Одновременно вызывайте `notifyItemChanged()` для тех элементов списка, где у вас есть поля ввода, которые надо заполнить. 3. В `onBindViewHolder()` элементов из п.2. заполняйте поле ввода текстом из переменной из п.1

Comment: Как по мне это бред, но если надо, то вам виднее. Одной из реализаций, я бы использовал DataBinding, где создал бы объект с полем: ObservableField<String> и прикрепил бы его к вьюшке (item_layout), а в onBindViewHolder() передавал бы всем создаваемым элементам списка этот объект.

Comment: там я сам понимаю,что бред.но мне так нужно